# How to make xsl:copy keep html entities literally?

Tags: xslt, html-entities

I have an input xml like this:

```
...    
<member name="&#916;"></member>
...
```

When I'm applying the identity transformation (i.e. I want to keep this part of the input and I want to change other parts of it) then I get this:

```
...
<member name="Δ"></member>
...
```

How can I keep that part **literally**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in XSLT 2.0, you can use

```
<xsl:character-map name="charmap">
    <xsl:output-character character="&#916;" string="&amp;#916;"/>
</xsl:character-map>
```